# How are log files persisted with the Logstash charm?

Tags: juju

I'd like to use the Logstash Juju charm and was wondering how the log files are persisted. In other words, if I lose a Logstash instance will I still have access to past logs?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there isn't much safe guard if you're just using the [logstash-indexer](http://jujucharms.com/charms/precise/logstash-indexer) charm with no datastore. However, if you add the [elasticsearch charm](http://jujucharms.com/charms/precise/elasticsearch) to your logstash-indexer instance, then the data will instead be stored there. So if the indexer does go away, the data is still kept in elasticsearch and should still be reachable by [Kabana](http://jujucharms.com/charms/precise/kibana) or other means. However, if elasticsearch went away you'd be in the same situation as before, where the data wouldn't be available anymore.